# google map problem

Tags: google-maps, many-to-many, mashup

I got a google map and I load it but I want to change the direction or center by changing the center,how can I do this? I got a code like this to load the map:

```
function putmap(x) {
           if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
```

```
            map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("Map"));

            // Create new geocoding object
            geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();

            // Retrieve location information, pass it to addToMap()
            geocoder.getLocations(x, addToMap);

        }
```

}
I want to change the value of x by say entering a new value on the textbox how can I do this...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Are you the Google Maps API or simply trying to navigate a map?

Comment: I successfully loaded the map to my webpage but I want to change the center dynamically,how can I do this?

Comment: Your question needs more detail.  Please update it.

Comment: Yeah, are you just looking for the docs for `setCenter`? If so, here you go: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#Map

Answer (score 2):

Well, you change the center by doing

```
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(lat, lng), map.getZoom());
```

Look [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#Map) for more detail. If you know the zoom level you want, you can use that instead of `map.getZoom()`.

Comment: If you don't want to change the zoom, you don't need to specify it.  Just use: map.setCenter(new GLatLng(lat, lng));

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Map2 API?  If so, just use the `setCenter()` method:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map2(document.getElementById("map"));
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0), 2);
```

[See the docs](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/documentation/) for more help getting started.

Answer (score 0):

Give your textbox an id, then you can write

geocoder.getLocations(document.getElementById("mytextbox").value, addToMap);